# Peut-on faire suivre « aussi … que » d'une proposition ?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, subordonnées, comparatifs

Est-ce que la phrase suivante est correcte ?

> Veuillez laisser la salle aussi propre que vous l'avez trouvé.

Comment: À part une faute d'accord à « trouvé**e** », cette phrase est correcte.

Answer (score 6):

Le COD étant avant le verbe, il faut accorder le verbe en genre:

> Veuillez laisser la salle aussi propre que vous l'avez trouvé**e**.

Sur [ce lien](http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/COD.php), 2 exemples concordent avec la construction :

> « La remarque **que** j'ai fait**e** est pertinente »: COD "que" placé devant le verbe pour "la remarque"
>   « La mer ? Oui, je **l'** ai vu**e** » : COD "l'" placé devant le verbe pour "la mer"

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ah ? Pourtant je corrige la faute pour qu'elle soit correcte, avec la justification de la correction...

Answer (score 3):

La construction est correcte (avec une correction sur le COD: *trouvée*).

Ce genre de construction est du type:

**pseudo-adjectif = aussi/plus/moins + adjectif + groupe nominal ou relative.**

> **Plus** propre que l'autre salle.
>
> **Plus** grand que je (ne) le pensais.
>
> **Moins** dur que tu (ne) le disais.
>
> **Aussi** grandiose que tu le montrais.

Comment: Tu ne mets pas de "ne" avec "moins" ni avec "aussi"? Pourtant je les mettrais.

Comment: @Vérace . exact, mis sur l'un et pas sur l'autre sans m'en rendre compte. Les 2 sont acceptables. Avec ne, c'est plus stylé. Mais pas avec aussi, à ma connaissance.